# xdot URL feature

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using xdot to build my own custom graphs by reading out a file containing dot syntax. The XDot page http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/XDot#Embedding mentions the feature of adding the URL tag to nodes to display information when clicked. I tried to add it to my dot file without success. Can I use this feature in the xdot ROS package? If so, an example is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11401/xdot-url-feature/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on a diff of the Xdot.py and ours, it appears the URL feature was more recently added (it's hard to tell as xdot.py doesn't have version numbers or accurate change logs).

It probably wouldn't take much work to merge in the feature changes to support the URL feature
The current version is forked with various minor patches due to our higher-level usages.  I'm swamped right now so would appreciate any patch to this affect.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1